# Why geting NoClassDefFoundError when initializing PhantomJS driver instance?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

This is my code to launch the phantomjs driver. But getting exception at first line. Help appreciated!!

```
driver=new PhantomJSDriver();
wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
driver.get(url);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.manage().window().maximize();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"gwt-debug-submit_button\"]")));
```

Comment: Need to share exception as well..:)

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/browserlaunchers/Proxies
 at org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService.createDefaultService(PhantomJSDriverService.java:178)
 at org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver.<init>(PhantomJSDriver.java:99)
 at org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver.<init>(PhantomJSDriver.java:89)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the exception in a formatted manner. Also, include the versions of all the relevant libraries and SDKs.

Comment: Thanks for your concern. The problem is solved. :)